# View transition in SwiftUI doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: swiftui, transition

I'm trying to understand how SwiftUI transitions work using a very simple code, but my understanding isn't sufficient, apparently. Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var change = false

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(change ? .red : .green)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .transition(.slide)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    change.toggle()
                }
            }
}
```

My thinking goes like this: the Rectangle depends on the `change` property, so when it changes, a new Rectangle, with a different colour, should be created to replace the old one. And since this change is requested with animation, and there is a `slide` transition specified, I should see a sliding transition.

Instead, I see the default fade-in/fade-out transition. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions can be used to show movement when a view is replaced by another view. In your example, you only have one view and are simply changing the color. The change of color is animated, but there's no movement involved because it's the same view.

To see a transition (with movement), you need to switch between different views. Using a `ZStack` is often a good way to do this. Here's how it can work for your example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var change = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if change {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                change.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As it happens, colors are a bit of a special case, because they can also be views in their own right. So another way to get the colors to slide in and out would be to apply the color as an overlay to your Rectangle, instead of setting the color as a property on the Rectangle:

```swift
        Rectangle()
            .overlay {
                if change {
                    Color.red.transition(.slide)
                } else {
                    Color.green.transition(.slide)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    change.toggle()
                }
            }
```

However, the principle is still the same: if you want to see a transition involving movement, you need to be switching between different views.